# Why am I getting "\r\n\r\n0" passed into my success function?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I can't figure out why `retInfo` below is `"\r\n\r\n0"` whenever I make the AJAX call.

```
function getEightMore ( )
{
    // show loading icon
    $('#load-more-row img').css('visibility', 'visible');

    // get the next 8 or fewer projects 
    formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('numItemsLoaded', numItemsLoaded)
    formdata.append('workType', workType )
    formdata.append('action', 'get_eight_more');
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        data: formdata,
        success: function (retInfo) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(retInfo)); // test                
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });     

    //$('#load-more-row img').css('visibility', 'hidden');
}
```

Server-side code:

```
// make AJAX handler for getting more projects or case studies 
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_eight_more', 'get_eight_more' );

function get_eight_more ( )
{
    $workType = $_POST['workType'];
    $numItemsLoaded = $_POST['numItemsLoaded'];
    global $wpdb;
    $nstr = strval(intval($numItemsLoaded) + 1);
    $nextEightRows = $wpdb->query('SELECT id,name,sumsmall FROM ' . $_POST['workType'] . 'ORDER BY postdate LIMIT 8, ' . $nstr);
    echo(json_encode($nextEightRows));  

}
```

I'm not even sure it has anything to do with the body of my PHP function `get_eight_more ( )`, because I've tried changing the it to stuff like `die(json_encode("This is a test"));` and I still get `"\r\n\r\n0"` back. Where is that mysterious string coming from? What does it mean?

Comment: It means two new-lines and `0`.

Comment: @Teemu And what on earth is making those?

Comment: Those double newlines could easily come from whitespace in the script/template files, between closing and opening PHP tags.

Comment: If you remove the echo so there is no output do you still get the newlines? If you changed the echo to a var_dump are the new lines part of the string output? Make sure there are no newlines at the top of your page before the opening php tag or any included files. Also double check any parent files that this is being included to. That would be added as output and is one likely place for the newlines. As for the `0`, do a var_dump on `$nextEightRows` and make sure your query isn't failing returning false/0. I see you are missing a space before the `ORDER BY` in the query also.

Comment: Plus, adding `$_POST['-anything-']` directly to a query is bad and is called sql injection. Anyone can change the value in the post to whatever they want meaning they can change your query to return more/different rows or do pretty much any malicious thing they want to your database including pulling stuff like username and password hashes.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I know about SQL injection, I'll worry about that later

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `die();` after you echo your response (that's where 0 is from).

```
echo json_encode($nextEightRows);  
die(); // or wp_die();
```

Comment: I changed it to `die` and the `0` was still there

Comment: Why do you have to use die now?

Comment: Quote for you from WP codex example `wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response`